# LockerService causes access error when managed package component tries to load js from its static resource

Tags: static-resources, locker-service, cross-domain

I turned on LockerService to test our Lightning components and I get the following error when loading a page.  Our component is trying to load a .js file from its own static resource and it throws the following error.  Adding the domain to CORS doesn't help.  I don't know what to do next to try to resolve this problem.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://<mydomainname>--dev3--kkltng.cs87.visual.force.com/resource/kkltng__hierarchy/lodash.min.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://<mydomainname>--dev3--c.cs87.visual.force.com' is therefore not allowed access.`